# What is wrong with this regex pattern in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, grepl

I am working on an exercise to create a regex which filters strings with temperatures.

The idea is to catch all which have structures such as: "-0.4 F", " 5 C", "- 0.6 C" and so on. Here's my try:

```
temp <- c("La temp es de 0.4 F", "La temp es de -5F", "nada", "tampoco nada",
    "La temp es de - 0.6    C")

temp[grepl("([+-]?\\s+[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]*)?)\\s+([CF])$)\\1\\2", temp)]
```

My reasoning:

1. `[+-]?\\s*[0-9]+` allows optional positive or negative signs (but just one) plus optional spaces (none required) and digits from 0-9 (at least one required). This defines my first group
2. `(?:\\.[0-9]*)?)\\s+([CF])$)` defines the second group. According to this [text](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjTj5iqlc3nAhVIlKwKHXNqBOgQFjAAegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxlb.es%2FMastering%2520Regular%2520Expressions%2520(Friedl-2006).pdf&usg=AOvVaw3-cnSkc9JkyvCtAxWyQLYy), the `(?:` notation stands for opening parenthesis where there can be an optional group. In this case, `\\.[0-9]*)?`is the optional group (decimal period and some digits). Then, `\\s+` defines empty spaces (none required) and `([CF])$` is the end of the string (mandatory).

If I'm well reasoning, I have two regex groups, that's why I use `\\1\\2` back references. My code doesn't work, so I get `character(0)` as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *Recommended Pattern:*

If it was me starting from scratch, I would've used the following:

```r
grep('\\d[^a-z]*[CF]', temp, value = TRUE)


 # > [1] "La temp es de 0.4 F"      "La temp es de -5F"        "La temp es de - 0.6    C"
```

`\\d` there is a digit

`[^a-zA-Z]*` not followed by any character in range of a-z but any other characters

`[CF]` and at the end followed by C or F

#### *Explanation:*

There are bunch of problems with that regex you have (if I'm not mistaken):

1. You use groups in the replacement not in the matching pattern. I am not sure why you have `\\1\\2` at the end of your pattern.
2. You have unnecessary grouping. Different parts of your desired pattern are consequent and you want to merely find them, not replace them.
3. You assume C or F always happen at the end of the line.
4. You have an extra parentheses.

I am not an expert, so there may be other issues.

***N. B.*** Using online interpreters would be helpful here as they show/highlight some of the errors.

I started from your pattern and come up with the one below:

```
[+-]?\\s*[0-9+][\\.]?[0-9+]?\\s*[CF]
```

Here's a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G4m3sR/5/) which also provides detailed explanation of the pattern above. You can paste the first pattern here to get a better explanation than what I provided as well.

Comment: Wow. Nice and simple. Do you know any useful reference which has a good explanation on regex specifically with R? The book I talk about in my question is PERL oriented. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera I am not book-oriented, which is not essentially a good approach. I am more of a learn it as you need it person. This cheatsheet is what I used to rely on https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf&amp;ved=2ahUKEwj54dXiis_nAhXvuFkKHVzjBDUQFjAAegQIARAC&amp;usg=AOvVaw3lvc-j9imym_-7OO9Esp8D&amp;cshid=1581616039854 ; nowadays, I just go to regex101, link in my answer, and test it out till I get it right.

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
grep('-?\\d+(\\.\\d+\\s+)?[CF]', temp, value = TRUE)
#[1] "La temp es de 0.4 F" "La temp es de -5F"  "La temp es de - 0.6    C"
```

`-?` - Is an optional negative sign

`\\d+` - followed by a one or more numbers

`(\\.\\d+\\s+)?` - with an optional decimal number and whitespace(s)

`[CF]` - followed by either C or F.